# ASP.NET MVC Code First Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been creating ASP.NET MVC-based projects using Model and DB First. This time I have to use Code First approach. I have read several tutorials on it, now I want to test it. But get error' don't know why.
This is my model class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }   
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the context class:

```
public class CompanyEntities:DbContext
{
    public CompanyEntities()
        : base("name=CompanyEntities")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

This is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CompanyEntities" connectionString="Data Source=MOON\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=c1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pppppp" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the action method of Employees controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CompanyEntities>());
            return View(db.Employees.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When I call /Employees/Index action, I get this error: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in MvcCompanyCF.dll but was not handled in user code". Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The **Database.SetInitializer()** method should be kept before the Context object is initialized. In ASP.NET web application the best place will be in Application_Start() event of Global.asax file.

reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/814618/Use-of-Database-SetInitializer-method-in-Code-Firs

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, you must use `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` for code first.